# Skype in Wine duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I recently found a way to run Skype in Wine. I searched askubuntu, and found a bunch of duplicate questions. I answered the question with the most upvotes and flagged the others as duplicate, but they don't seem tot get closed.

Answered question: [How to run Windows Skype on Ubuntu using Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-use-skype-on-ubuntu/722140)

Duplicates:

- [Getting an up-to-date Version of Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594220/getting-an-up-to-date-version-of-skype?lq=1)
- ["skype can't connect" error using wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721412/skype-cant-connect-error-using-wine?lq=1)
- [Skype with wine crashes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598278/skype-with-wine-crashes?lq=1)
- [Error while trying to run Skype via Wine in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579988/error-while-trying-to-run-skype-via-wine-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit)

There are also a bunch of questions about video conferencing on Skype on Ubuntu (only possible using Windows Skype on Wine)

Answered question: [Unable to do group video call and group screen share using Skype 4.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534186/unable-to-do-group-video-call-and-group-screen-share-using-skype-4-3)

Duplicates:

- [skype conference call problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583922/skype-conference-call-problem)
- [Cannot make Conference Call using Skype on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619962/cannot-make-conference-call-using-skype-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [Workaround for Skype group video call](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677306/workaround-for-skype-group-video-call)
- [Skype 4.3 on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529607/skype-4-3-on-ubuntu) (
  although this one is marked as a duplicate of the wrong question)

PS: I see that @Mitch deleted my answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619962/cannot-make-conference-call-using-skype-on-ubuntu-14-04) question and I'm not sure why...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I answered the question with the most upvotes and flagged the others
>   as duplicate, but they don't seem tot get closed."

This is because it takes five votes to close a question (from users with enough rep), your vote alone will not close the question, it just goes to review.

The thing with the close votes queue is, it is very large, 515 questions right now. As far as I know, the questions are presented to reviewers at random, so it can take a long time for a question to be closed, even if it is obvious.

Each of your questions has multiple close votes, so people do agree with you on this but people have other things to do, we are all volunteers, give it a week or so and check the votes then.

> "PS: I see that @Mitch deleted my answer to this question and I'm not
>   sure why...? "

I can't speak on this, but my advice is go  to chat and try to ping the user with @ and the users name, if they have been to chat in the last, I think, three days, they will be notified of your ping and you can ask them.

Comment: I'll ping him, thanks. I didn't know the close queue was so big... I did my daily 20, hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

The delete part I can answer myself: I was posting duplicate answers, I should've just answered one and mark the others as duplicate.